# Consultant - visa

Tags: working-visas

I am a LTD. company consultant contracted to a Canadian entity.  The Canadian entity just opened an office in the USA and would like me to go there to do some work. Am I able to get a work visa under E2 in order to do this work in the US? I am paid directly to my own LTD company and pay my own taxes and insurances. 
Thank you,

Comment: Are you a Canadian citizen?

Comment: What is your citizenship and where are you currently located?

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that you are a citizen of Canada.

The [requirements for the E-2 visa](https://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/temporary-workers/e-2-treaty-investors) suggest that you are not eligible for an E-2 visa as a treaty investor.  In particular, it sounds like this would be a "marginal enterprise":

> Marginal Enterprises
>
> The investment enterprise may not be marginal.  A marginal enterprise is one that does not have the present or future capacity to generate more than enough income to provide a minimal living for the treaty investor and his or her family.  Depending on the facts, a new enterprise might not be considered marginal even if it lacks the current capacity to generate such income.  In such cases, however, the enterprise should have the capacity to generate such income within five years from the date that the treaty investor’s E-2 classification begins.  See 8 CFR 214.2(e)(15).

For example, you could make a case that you are starting a consulting business that would generate enough income to support a staff at some point in the next five years.  But that doesn't sound like your actual goal here.

You might qualify as an *employee* of a treaty investor, but to do that, your employer would have to be either a person present in the US as an E-2 treaty investor or a company "at least 50% owned by persons *in the United States* who [are Canadian]" (emphasis added).  Furthermore, you would have to go on their payroll rather than continuing to work as a consultant.

If your profession is on the [NAFTA occupation list](https://www.nafsa.org/_/file/_/amresource/8cfr2146.htm), you might consider a [TN visa](https://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/temporary-workers/tn-nafta-professionals).